# WP7 Crash when trying to create instance of WriteableBitmap

Tags: windows-phone-7

everyone, I've met an strange problem when saving picture to media library, my application crashed without rising an exception. Here is my saving code.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    try
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(InkPrest, InkPrest.RenderTransform); // Crash here, the actualHeight of InkPrest is 2370.0 

        bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, (int)InkPrest.ActualWidth, (int)InkPrest.ActualHeight, 0, 100);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        library.SavePicture(DateTime.Now.ToString(), stream.GetBuffer());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have debuged step by step, the app crash at

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(InkPrest, InkPrest.RenderTransform); // Crash here, the actualHeight of InkPrest is 2370.0
```

Any idea on solving this problem?

============================================

Try to save several images

The uielement is 704 * 2370

```
TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
transform.Transform(new Point(0,0));
double MaxHeight = 800;
double height = InkPrest.ActualHeight;
int saveCount = 0;
int succeedCount = 0;
while (height > 0)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            double actualRenderHeight = Math.Min(height, MaxHeight);
            WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)InkPrest.ActualWidth, (int)actualRenderHeight);

            bitmap.Render(InkPrest, transform); //Crash here, also no exception.
            bitmap.Invalidate();

            height -= actualRenderHeight;
            transform.Y -= actualRenderHeight;

            bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, (int)InkPrest.ActualWidth, (int)actualRenderHeight, 0, 100);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
            Picture pic = library.SavePicture(manuscriptFile.Title + DateTime.Now.ToString(), stream.GetBuffer());
            saveCount++;
            if (pic != null)
            {
                succeedCount++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this on the emulator, or only on real devices?

Comment: Both on emulator and device. crash whithout exception.

Comment: I guess the crash reson is that my picture is longger than 2000. I am testing on it.

Comment: I think that is exactly the reason.  2048 is the limit I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are instantiating writeablebitmap in uithread or some other created thread. you need to create writeablebitmap in uithread.